# Get Result - Kotlin startActivityForResult does not deliver any result

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult

Halllo, my *BarcodeActivity* is called by *startActivityForResult* through my *PCActivity*. The value of the scanned barcode should then be returned back to the *PCActivity* and inserted in a text field there. Unfortunately, I do not get a value back. However, the app does not crash either. Here is my code.

**PCActivity:**

```
sn_mb.setDrawableRightTouch {
        val intent = Intent(this@PCActivity, BarcodeActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
}
```

[...]

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        val returnedSN = intent.getStringExtra("return_sn")
        sn_mb.setText(returnedSN)
    } else {
        sn_mb.setText("FEHLER!")
    }
}
```

**BarcodeActivity**

```
saveBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val sn = editTextBarcode.text.toString()
        sn.toString()
        if (sn!= "") {
            val returnIntent:Intent = Intent()
            returnIntent.putExtra("return_sn", sn)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
            finish()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Das ist keine gültige Seriennummer",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }
```

I hope someone can explain or help me with this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint and debug?

Comment: I am reading the Logcat but there are no errors.

Comment: I see one more issue with your code, you are putting int in the intent extra and reading string. Try with the same data type.  returnIntent.putExtra("return_sn", "1"). You might be getting null in getStringExtra

Comment: To be honsest I don't understand. I am using returnIntent.putExtra("return_sn", "1"). Where do I put int into intent extra? My barcode scanner is scanning letters either, so i cannot work with int.

Comment: I don't think you should edit your question to fix the problem after getting the solution, because then the question isn't helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not passing the scanned bar code value (`sn`) to the intent(`returnIntent`) in your `BarCodeActivity`.

First make sure `sn` is `String` since you want to pass a `StringExtra`, therefore:

`val sn = editTextBarcode.text.toString()`

And then pass `sn` to your return intent:

`returnIntent.putExtra("return_sn", sn)`

Notice that in your code you are passing integer `1` instead of `sn`.

EDIT:
One more minor fix to your code, didn't notice it:

`val returnIntent:Intent = getIntent()`

Notice that it's `getIntent()` instead of `Intent()`

Comment: I tried so, i update the code in my question. Unfortunately i still do not receive any result.

Comment: Thank you, with your help and the help of @dimsuz everything is working :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are extracting your data from the wrong place.

Replace

```kotlin
val returnedSN = intent.getStringExtra("return_sn")
```

with

```kotlin
val returnedSN = data.getStringExtra("return_sn")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With your help and the help of @Kidus everything is working.